# How to convert a JSONObject to a Java Bean with string variables?

Tags: java, json, parsing, javabeans, basex

How can I convert a `JSONObject` to a `PersonBean` as below?  I have an intermediary `Person` with a `name` field and a `List<String` for other attributes.  The `List` is of indeterminate size, but less than ten items.

My thinking is to create `PersonBean` with additional `String` fields and then manually copy values from the `List` into bean setters.

But, of course I'm getting out of bound errors when creating a `PersonBean` because the `List` might be empty:

```
package groupBaseX.io;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PersonBeanBuilder {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PersonBeanBuilder.class.getName());
    private Person person = null;
    private PersonBean personBean = new PersonBean();

    private PersonBeanBuilder() {
    }

    public PersonBeanBuilder(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
        log.fine(person.toString());
        log.fine(person.getName());
        personBean.setName(person.getName());

        String a = person.getAttributes().get(0);
        String b = person.getAttributes().get(1);
        String c = person.getAttributes().get(2);
        String d = person.getAttributes().get(3);
        String e = person.getAttributes().get(4);

        personBean.setA(a);
        personBean.setB(b);
        personBean.setC(c);
        personBean.setD(d);
        personBean.setE(e);

    }

    public PersonBean getPersonBean() {
        return personBean;
    }

}
```

Certainly, I can just use `try/catch` but is there not a more elegant solution?  The above code is very much a kludge.

because the underlying `JSON`, in a `JSONArray`, is of indeterminate size.  For practical purposes, I'm only interested in the name and the first few attributes for each object below:

```
[
  {
    "0":"z10",
    "1":"y9",
    "2":"x7",
    "3":"atrib6",
    "name":"alice"
  },
  {
    "0":"home5",
    "1":"cell4",
    "name":"sue"
  },
  {
    "0":"phone3",
    "1":"phone2",
    "2":"phone1",
    "name":"joe"
  },
  {
    "name":"people"
  }
]
```

Some `JSONObject` will of course have zero attributes, but certainly less than ten.  Just looking to [create](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60268157/262852) a Java Bean from the above `JSON`, which is from `BaseX`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the somewhat reasonable approach I settled on:

```
package groupBaseX.io;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PersonBeanBuilder {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PersonBeanBuilder.class.getName());
    private Person person = null;
    private PersonBean personBean = new PersonBean();

    private PersonBeanBuilder() {
    }

    public PersonBeanBuilder(Person person) {
        this.person = person;

    }

    public PersonBean getPersonBean() {
        personBean.setName(person.getName());

        Map<String, AF> map = new HashMap<>();

        AF attributeField = AF.GARBAGE;
        person.getAttributes().forEach((s) -> {
            map.put(s, attributeField.getType(s));
        });

        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            switch (map.get(key)) {
                case HOME_PHONE:
                    log.fine(AF.HOME_PHONE.toString());
                    personBean.setHomePhone1(key);
                    break;
                default:
                    log.fine(AF.HOME_PHONE.toString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        return personBean;
    }

}
```

enum:

```
package groupBaseX.io;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AttributeParser {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AttributeParser.class.getName());
    private List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

    private AttributeParser() {
    }

    public AttributeParser(List<String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    // ^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$  phone
    // ^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$     zip
    public void foo() {

        boolean isPhone = false;
        boolean isZip = false;
        for (String s : attributes) {
            int x = 3;
            isPhone = false;
            isZip = false;

        }
    }

}
```

But, still quite awkward.  The starting point is `JSON` so I'm sure this has been figured by smarter monkeys than me already.